# Keep number intact

Tags: excel, csv

Hi I am trying to save. exls file as .csv file, I am not able to keep number format intact, it changes to Scientific number. Would like to keep number as it as I am trying to send SMS to the number.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show an example of the wrong csv and what you expect the csv to be? According to the Excel documentation, numbers should be saved exactly how you see them in Excel

Comment: Before save, explicitly format the numeric fields as you want them saved and ensure that the column width is large enough to display without showing ####.  Do this for date fields too so you don't get 41234.whatever as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your response..
I went through other similar question,the trick is to put number as ="996753xxxx".The format would remain intact.